# Is it possible to change the path of the JSESSIONID cookie?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jsessionid

By default, Glassfish stores the JSESSIONID cookie at the context path, for example "/mysite". Is it possible to change this path, for example to "/mysite/admin"? I would like the session to be only valid in part of my website, without having to split it into two separate websites.

Comment: Hi Kees, I am also facing the same. Did you get the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the other part of your web site should just be configured as another web context? The general idea is that each web context has its own set of sessions, and you don't share nor split them.

Comment: "using another web context" means making it a different WAR, right?

Comment: Yeah. If you have a lot of overlapping code for the paths, you could just deploy it twice and have each one configured to only work for its side.